# How to force a manual line break in author list in revtex4-1?

Tags: line-breaking, revtex, author-number

I am using `revtex4-1`, `prl` style. I have 6 authors. I want 4 authors in the first line of author list and 2 in the 2nd one. However, Latex is breaking the line after the 3rd author. I am using:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,superscriptaddress,amsmath,amssymb,prl,aps,floatfix]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[backref,pdffitwindow,colorlinks,linkcolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breakurl} 
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{authblk}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{} 

\begin{document}

\title{my tittle}

\author{John 1}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally.}
\affiliation{affil1}
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{John 2}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally.}
\affiliation{affil2}
\affiliation{affil3}

\author{John 3}
\affiliation{affil4}

\author{John 4}
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{john 5}
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{John 6}
\affiliation{affil1}
\affiliation{affil2}
\affiliation{affil5}

\begin{abstract}
my abstract... 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have tried `\mbox` to lump together the first 4 authors and that doesn't work. I have tried `\nolinebreak` after the 3rd author and also it does not work either. I have also tried smaller font size to see if it helps but then it looks weird. Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! When you adding code try to select it and press `{}` button (else it is added as a text)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I can't seem to replicate exactly your problem (it's not breaking after the 3rd author), but try `\author{\\john 5}`?

Comment: it doesn't break to me too... May be you have to extend your MWE by adding more code like changes in packages or definitions you made before reduce so much your code

Comment: Thanks all for  the suggestions. I tried \author{\\John 5} and latex now breaks after the 4 author. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

A bit of a manual solution, but you can force line breaks in the author list of `revtex4-1` by adding `\\` before `john5`, in your case.

See the minimal example below.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,superscriptaddress,amsmath,amssymb,prl,floatfix]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{my tittle}

\author{John 1}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally.}
\affiliation{affil1}
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{John 2}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally.}
\affiliation{affil2}
\affiliation{affil3}

\author{John 3}
\affiliation{affil4}

\author{John 4}
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{\\john 5} % <--------------
\affiliation{affil2}

\author{John 6}
\affiliation{affil1}
\affiliation{affil2}
\affiliation{affil5}

\begin{abstract}
my abstract... 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: break]